# How to get proper gradient with react-native-linear-gradient

Tags: react-native, svg

```html
<svg width="287" height="51" viewBox="0 0 287 51" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <rect width="287" height="51" rx="8" fill="url(#paint0_linear_317_287)"/>
    <defs>
    <linearGradient id="paint0_linear_317_287" x1="642.63" y1="-71.5962" x2="3.27769" y2="38.4169" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
        <stop stop-color="#FF4B00"/>
        <stop offset="1" stop-color="#D057BD"/>
    </linearGradient>
    </defs>
</svg>
```

I have this linearGradient in svg and want to achieve same with react-native-linear-gradient but unable to do so? I want to use react-native-linear-gradient because I do not have flexibility to style as per demand with svg or at least I don't know how to.

Want to achieve same svg linearGradientin with react-native-linear-gradient

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't achive it with react-native-linear-gradient. However, you can do it with https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-svg.
For example your component would be:

```js
const SvgComponent = (props) => (
  <svg
    width={287}
    height={51}
    fill="none"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    {...props}
  >
    <rect width={287} height={51} rx={8} fill="url(#a)" />
    <defs>
      <linearGradient
        id="a"
        x1={642.63}
        y1={-71.596}
        x2={3.278}
        y2={38.417}
        gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
      >
        <stop stopColor="#FF4B00" />
        <stop offset={1} stopColor="#D057BD" />
      </linearGradient>
    </defs>
  </svg>
)

export default SvgComponent
```

You can build the same with this website https://react-svgr.com/playground/